# SQL Query works but it takes too much time to complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance, sql-query-store

I have this "simple" SQL query and it works but it is taking 11 minutes to complete.
Can you tell me if there is a way to simplify the code or something in order to get a better performance and a faster response.
Note: The query has been being running in the SQL Management Studio 18.6 in the Server (Windows Server 2019).
Thank you in advance.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[ScanJobLog]
WHERE (ScanJobLog.StationID = '207' OR  ScanJobLog.StationID = '208' OR  ScanJobLog.StationID = '218' OR  ScanJobLog.StationID = '219') AND (ScanJobLog.Occurred BETWEEN '2023-03-28' AND '2023-03-29')
AND (ScanJobLog.ScanJobResult = '2')
AND (Scan LIKE 'L001620321%')
```

Comment: Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? What are the indexes on your table `dbo.ScanJobLog`? As you've tagged Query Store as well have you noticed the plan has changed for the query or something?

Comment: I would suggest to remove DISTINCT. And please also clarify if you have any indexes on [dbo].[ScanJobLog]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I see that it has an index (Clustered). I did not created the DataBase but I assume the Index has been created automatic. Should I create a new one? I have very little experience creating index. I can share an image (screenshot) with you if you want so you can see the index in the DB but I can't paste it here :(

Comment: Clustered indexes aren't created automatically no. What we really need is the execution plan, and likely the *definitions* of any indexes on the table; images of the indexes aren't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple, you can create a nonclustered index, reference: [(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16)](https://(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16)).

I can determine the required nonclustered index without the execution plan since you provided your where-clause, and the where-clause in your example identifies what columns to index.  You also said in comments you had no other indexes other than the clustered index (which is in all likelihood also your primary key since making the primary key the clustered index is the default SQL Server behavior).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncx_scanJobLog_StationID_Occurred_ScanJobResult_Scan
 ON [dbo].[ScanJobLog] (StationID, Occurred, ScanJobResult, Scan)
```

A caveat is if any primary key columns were in the where clause- then they can be excluded.  There is obviously more to say on the subject of indexes but this is going out of scope of your original question.